# Why does my UpdateAsync(user) method fail the first time, claiming user doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-boilerplate

I have a method that signs a user in and attempts to update the user if the `viewModel` is different than `user` object. The behaviour I'm seeing is confusing.

Every time the method executes, if the `user` was not previously logged in, the line `await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);` fails with the exception: `"There is no user with id: 99"` (or whatever `id` value). However, if the `user` *was* previously logged in, the line works.

So for example,

1. User starts up the app (not currently logged in) and clicks button to post `viewModel` to server.
2. The app logs the `user` in,
3. If the `viewModel` is different than the existing `user`'s data, the server attempts to update it.
4. This update will fail with `"There is no user with id: 99"`
5. User clicks button again and posts the same data to the server. (this time `user` has been logged in from previous failed post)
6. `viewModel` is still different than existing data (remember, the update failed last time)
7. `await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);` works and the record is updated.

The following is the method:

```
[UnitOfWork]
public async Task<AjaxResponse> Post(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
        var loginResult = await _userManager.LoginAsync(viewModel.UserName, viewModel.Password, viewModel.TenancyName);

        User user;
        if (loginResult.Result == AbpLoginResultType.Success)
        {
            await SignInAsync(loginResult.User, loginResult.Identity);

            user = loginResult.User;

            if (user.AccessToken != viewModel.AccessToken)
            {
                user.AccessToken = viewModel.AccessToken;

                // why does this fail the first time?
                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            }
        }
        else 
        { 
            /* do some other UnitOfWork stuff below */
        }


        return new AjaxResponse(new MyResult
        {
            Name = user.Name + " " + user.Surname,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress,
            IsActive = user.IsActive,
            Success = true,
            UserId = user.UserId,
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I can confirm that a user with the id 99 *does* in fact exist in the database.

For the record, the following is the contents of `ex.StackTrace`

```
   at Abp.Authorization.Users.AbpUserManager`3.<GetUserByIdAsync>d__5b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Abp.Authorization.Users.AbpUserManager`3.<UpdateAsync>d__64.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyProject.Web.Controllers.Api.AccountApiController.<Post>d__16.MoveNext() in C:\dev\MyProject\MyProject.Web\Controllers\Api\AccountApiController.cs:line 146
```

I think one clue might be in the following query (intercepted with SQL Server Profiler) that gets executed before the update:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[AccessToken] AS [AccessToken], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress], 
    [Extent1].[TenantId] AS [TenantId], 
    [Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
    -- irrelevant stuff removed
    FROM [dbo].[AbpUsers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 
            ((([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NULL) AND (@DynamicFilterParam_1 IS NULL)) 
        OR  (([Extent1].[TenantId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[TenantId] = @DynamicFilterParam_1)) 
        OR (@DynamicFilterParam_2 IS NOT NULL)) AND (([Extent1].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_3) 
        OR (@DynamicFilterParam_4 IS NOT NULL)) AND ([Extent1].[EmailAddress] = @p__linq__0)',
        N'@DynamicFilterParam_1 int,@DynamicFilterParam_2 bit,@DynamicFilterParam_3 bit,@DynamicFilterParam_4 bit,@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)'
        ,@DynamicFilterParam_1=NULL,@DynamicFilterParam_2=NULL,@DynamicFilterParam_3=0,@DynamicFilterParam_4=NULL,@p__linq__0=N'myemail@mail.com'
```

Here, we can see that `@DynamicFilterParam_1=NULL`. The variable `@DynamicFilterParam_1` corresponds to the value for `[Extent1].[TenantId]`. If I manually assign the value `2` (which is the value associated with the record in the db) instead of `NULL` and rerun the query, it returns the record as I expect.

When I execute the method the second time, I can see that TenantId is correctly assigned the value of 2.

Why is the value corresponding to TenantId being assigned NULL the first time? Why does the `UpdateAsync` method fail every first time? What can I do to make it work?

In response to the request below, the definition of UpdateAsync is available in [the asp.net boilerplate github](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero/blob/d8fbb0b7bf681101f94581fe075df6e15e0018ff/src/Abp.Zero/Authorization/Users/AbpUserStore.cs#L61)

Comment: pls post the code of  UpdateAsync

Comment: I've added a link to the source for UpdateAsync. It's on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of multitenancy. ABP does not know the TenantId before user login. You should manually Set tenant id to switch to the tenant of the user. My Login code is like that:

```
public virtual async Task<JsonResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginModel, string returnUrl = "", string returnUrlHash = "")
{
    var loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(loginModel.UsernameOrEmailAddress, loginModel.Password, loginModel.TenancyName);

    var tenantId = loginResult.Tenant == null ? (int?)null : loginResult.Tenant.Id;

    using (UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(tenantId))
    {
        if (loginResult.User.ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin)
        {
            loginResult.User.SetNewPasswordResetCode();

            return Json(new AjaxResponse
            {
                TargetUrl = Url.Action(
                    "ResetPassword",
                    new ResetPasswordViewModel
                    {
                        TenantId = tenantId,
                        UserId = SimpleStringCipher.Instance.Encrypt(loginResult.User.Id.ToString()),
                        ResetCode = loginResult.User.PasswordResetCode
                    })
            });
        }

        var signInResult = await _signInManager.SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(loginResult, loginModel.RememberMe);
        if (signInResult == SignInStatus.RequiresVerification)
        {
            return Json(new AjaxResponse
            {
                TargetUrl = Url.Action(
                    "SendSecurityCode",
                    new
                    {
                        returnUrl = returnUrl + (returnUrlHash ?? ""),
                        rememberMe = loginModel.RememberMe
                    })
            });
        }

        Debug.Assert(signInResult == SignInStatus.Success);

        await UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
        {
            returnUrl = GetAppHomeUrl();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrlHash))
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl + returnUrlHash;
        }

        return Json(new AjaxResponse { TargetUrl = returnUrl });
    }
}
```

The critical thing is the using `(UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(tenantId))` statement